Gnome Text Editor: permanent fake circumflex near cursor
So I've witnessed a seemingly new behavior in GNOME Text Editor: whenever I type a circumflex ^, whatever I type afterwards, it remains near the cursor until I press backspace, not producing any visible effect after the expected one (video of the effect happening).

It does not add a circumflex to any further compatible character;
It is not affected by pressing Enter;
I can hit circumflex again and produce the expected behavior;
When I press backspace it disappears along with the real character I just deleted.

In short it doesn't seem to actually be there, but this is just annoying. Is that a bug?

You haven't mentioned the version of GNOME Text Editor you use. I tried to reproduce that on version 47.2, but wasn't able.

Also, it really looks like a bug, so it's worth reporting it at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-text-editor/-/issues/

I use version 46.3 (no updates available on 24.04). I guess it's pointless to report if I'm not using the latest version...
